# Reference to non-static member function must be called on templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates, boost-asio

I have a class used to wrap boost::asio and I use templates to define delegates:

```
template <class T>
  struct Socket : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Socket<T>> {

    explicit Socket<T>(T &delegate, const std::string &socket) : endpoint_{socket} {
      socket_.reset(new asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket(service_));
      socket_->connect(endpoint_, delegate_.error_code);
      socket_->non_blocking(true);
    }

    void read() const noexcept {
      std::vector<byte> bytes;
      asio::async_read(*socket_, asio::buffer(bytes), asio::transfer_all(), delegate_.on_read);
    }

    virtual ~Socket<T>() noexcept = default;

   private:
    asio::io_service service_;
    std::unique_ptr<asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket> socket_;
    asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint endpoint_;
    T delegate_;
    std::vector<byte> buffer_;
  };
```

My problem is that passing the delegate method as a handler to `asio::async_read` results in the error

> Reference to non-static member function must be called

What's the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: I don't think that you cite the message correctly.

Comment: A minor point, but within the class body you can refer to `Socket<T>` as just `Socket`, for example in your constructor and destructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delegate.on_read` is a non-static member function, so it requires an object to be called on. You could use a lambda to bind the object argument:

```
auto read_handler = 
  [this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    on_read(ec, bytes_transferred);
  };
asio::async_read(*socket_, asio::buffer(bytes), 
                  asio::transfer_all(), read_handler);
```

Untested, but something like that should work.